# Why I get an error getting the value of a variable in my API?

Tags: php, android

Hi have this error when I try to send accents from android to an php api:

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **/storage/ssd1/452/8869452/myapi.php**

I use postman to test my API and I sent accenst with It and all works, but when I try to sent accents  from android I get the error.

```
$respuesta["mensaje"] = array();
$json=file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj=json_decode($json);
$idresp=filter_var($obj->idresp);`
```

My json object that I sent It is the next:

```
{
    "QR":"76CD1L3hOb",
    "idresp":"53",
    "idportador":"4"
}
```

My android code it's the next

```
 JSONObject jsonUpdate = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonUpdate.put("QR", QR);
                        jsonUpdate.put("idresp", idusuario);
                        jsonUpdate.put("idportador",txtidPortador.getText().toString().trim());

                        new AgregarPortador(dialogoRecuperarCuenta).execute("myURLofMyApi.php", jsonUpdate.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error :c", "El error:\n" + e);
                    }//Cierra catch
```

The asynchTask code:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String data = "";
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(strings[1]);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                    char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                    inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                    data += current;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: `var_dump($json);` what do you get?

Comment: I get a "String" character

Comment: Then your problem is not on PHP, is on android, where you are sending the data

Comment: What's the String character? You mean $json has a value of literally "String"?

Comment: What do you mean by _accents_???

Comment: How are you sending that from android?

Comment: @AbraCadaver characters that have "é" not "e"

Comment: @Pipe I'm sending with Asynchtask class of android with jsonObjects I will update question that you can see